# Wish ... No More/Anymore

Tags: grammar, adverbs, wish

I've came across a question which asks for the correct sentence:

1. I wish you wouldn't do rude remarks at me no more.
2. I wish you didn't make rude remarks about me no more.
3. I wish you wouldn't make rude remarks about me anymore.
4. I wish you wouldn't do any rude remarks about me anymore

The first and last ones don't seem to be correct due not following the "make...about" structure, But what about the other two? My guess is that it comes to the used adverb.
Are these sentences considered negative or positive when we want do use an adverb for them? Is it the wish/I don't wish that determines the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several of these are probably regional dialect in which double negatives are used to indicate negation.

- I ain't got no money.
- Ain't nobody's bizness but my own.
- I can't get no satisfaction.

Also, the use of "do...at me", rather than "make...about me",  and "wish you didn't" rather than "wish you wouldn't" is probably a dialect thing.

So, in short, any of your examples could be correct, in *spoken* English, depending on where you are and whom you are talking to.  In *written* Emglish, I would use #3.